# Numpy cross product of vertical vectors

Tags: python, numpy

I am looking for an elegant way to compute the cross product for vectors that have more lines than columns.

I tried: `np.cross([[a],[b],[c]],[[d],[e],[f]])` with a to f being floats and I got:

> ValueError: incompatible dimensions for cross product

I also tried to pass values 0 and 1 to optional parameters `axisa`, `axisb`, `axisc` and `axis` mentionned in the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cross.html), but it did not help.

If it is not possible to do that, does that mean that users are expected to prefer using vectors with shape (1,3) over (3,1) ?

Comment: I am hesitating to close because I made a mistake when doing my tests. On the other hand there is no such example in the documentation and this answer could be useful when found via a search engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any error message when doing:

```
a, b, c, d, e, f = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6

np.cross([[a],[b],[c]],[[d],[e],[f]], axis=0)
# array([[-3],
#        [ 6],
#        [-3]])
```

If the shape is (1, 3) instead of (3, 1), you can simply do

```
np.cross([a, b, c], [d, e, f])
# array([-3,  6, -3])
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what output you want.

If you want a scalar output that is `a*d + b*e + c*f`, then do:

```
np.dot([1,2,3],[4,5,6])
```

If you want a vector output that has 3 elements and is perpendicular to the first two vectors (output of the cross product), then do:

```
np.cross([1,2,3],[4,5,6])
```

No need for the second set of brackets in the example you gave =)